# Ridge regression using Gridsearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science, grid-search

i'm try to do my ridge regression model using Gridsearch. i got two score values. can someone explain difference of these two scores and what is the my ridge regression performance score among these both values?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
ridge_reg = Ridge()
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
params_Ridge = {'alpha': [1,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001,0] , "fit_intercept": [True, False]}
Ridge_GS = GridSearchCV(ridge_reg, param_grid=params_Ridge)
Ridge_GS.fit(x_train,y_train)
Ridge_GS.best_params_
#*{'alpha': 1, 'fit_intercept': True}*

Ridge_GS.score(x_test,y_test)
```

## *0.9113458106264926* this score i got from above code..

this is the second way i try

```
ridge_model = Ridge(random_state=3, **Ridge_GS.best_params_)
ridge_model.fit(x_test,y_test)
ridge_model.score(x_test,y_test)
```

## 0.9532468692139026 this score i got from second method.

Comment: is x_test and y_test for two models come from same split or two splits?

Comment: i identified my mistake..i think [ ridge_model.fit(x_test,y_test) ] should be correct as  [ ridge_model.fit(x_train,y_train) ] then this two code have same output values